# SQL server 2005 - user rights

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have created one user named "tuser" with create database rights in SQL server 2005.
and given the 'db_owner' database role of master and msdb database to "tuser".

From this user login when I run the script for create database then it will create new database.
But "tuser" don't have access that newly created database generated from script.

Any one have any idea?, I want to write the script so "tuser" have access that new created database after creation and can have add user permission of newly created database.

I want to give 'db_owner' database roles to "tuser" on that newly created database in the same script which create new database. The script run under 'tuser'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input.

i have given access of tuser to database from ehich the new database created.
now the issue is resolved.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Grant `securityadmin` server role to `[tuser]`

> Members of the securityadmin fixed
>   server role manage logins and their
>   properties. They can GRANT, DENY, and
>   REVOKE server-level permissions. They
>   can also GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE
>   database-level permissions.
>   Additionally, they can reset passwords
>   for SQL Server logins.

Comment: I want to give 'db_owner' database roles to "tuser" on that newly created database in the same script which create new database. The script run under 'tuser'.

Comment: On your script,after creating the DB: `USE [yourdb] GO CREATE USER [tuser] FOR LOGIN [tuser] GO EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'tuser' GO`

Comment: "On your script,after creating the DB: USE [yourdb] GO CREATE USER [tuser] FOR LOGIN [tuser] GO EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'tuser' GO " As above you have written statement USE [yourdb] when i run USE [yourdb] with tuser at that time i got error. 

Because tuser has DBcreator server role access and db_owner access for master and msdb database.

Comment: Can you post your full script. If you create the database under tuser login. It should already have db_owner permission.

Answer (score 1):

[CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28SQL.90%29.aspx) says

> Each database has an owner that can
>   perform special activities in the
>   database. The owner is the user that
>   creates the database. The database
>   owner can be changed by using
>   sp_changedbowner (Transact-SQL).

So tuser should own the DB already.

However, you could set up tuser as db_owner in the model db which used as the template for every db creation

BTW, why make tuser the owner of master and msdb?

Comment: I have given access of 'db_Owner' database roles for tuser to Model db as well, even it is not working.

Comment: It will work with db_owner. This is the point of db_owner. What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

If tuser doesn't have access to the new database it means is not the owner. The database owner cannot be denied access into his/her own database.

- How does the CREATE DATABASE statement look like? Do you have any AUTHORIZATION clause that would change the database ownership of the new database?
- Who is the actual owner of the new database? Check `SELECT name, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) FROM sys.databases;`